# James Rhodes plays Chopin during Front Row interview, but can you identify the piece?

Tags: classical-music, identify-this-song

On BBC Radio 4 2015-08-31 Front Row [did an interview with James Rhodes](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b067wf2w)

At 18m20s he introduces a piece he played for an agent, which he describes as a ridiculously difficult piece by Chopin. Unfortunately they do not name the piece, can you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identified by a friend through [musipedia](http://www.musipedia.org/result.html?sourceid=melody-url&tx_mpsearch_pi1%5bsubmit_button%5d=Search&tx_mpsearch_pi1%5bpc%5d=lilye%274+e%274+e%278+e%274+f%274+e%274+c%274+e%274+&filtertext=&coll=m&onlymatchfrom=0.3) as [Etude Opus 25 No 11 (Winter Wind)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObbvThI-unk)